# How can I remotely update in app text on xamarian.ios and xamarian.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

What is the best way to update a text box in an app remotely. I want to add a text box that will be updated daily and was wondering what is the best way to do it on xamarian.ios and xamarian.android. Would something like firebase work well for that or is there a better way to do this if I want to update it daily with different text.

This is not necessary, but is there a way to set up text updates for each day at one time and then as the date changes the text does as well so that way I can set up the whole week or something like that at once.

I appreciate any help with this, if you guys know a way to do this or have a guide I can follow I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!

Comment: simply make an http request to a server every time the app starts (or the first start for the day).  Update your server daily to display the new text

Comment: Thanks for the response, I should've been more clear with the question. Not really looking to setup a server or anything special for this its a very simple app I just need text to be changed, I was looking for maybe a free service like firebase or anything like that that can store text and then just have the app retrieve it. I just wanted to see if anyone knows what the best and quickest way would be. Thanks again

Comment: you could host a json file on AWS or another file hosting service for next to nothing

Comment: I will give that a shot, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can update text in the application using Firebase Remote Config service. You do not require to build application every time. You also do not require to set up any server for this.

Check below link for implementation details.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/

Below link is for NuGet package for Firebase config.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Config/

Comment: Thank you for the help, would it let me use the same thing for both android and IOS or would they have to be updated separate ?

Comment: It will allow to use same thing for both. you need to manage on app side.